# Problem in setting a variable defined in an enclosing scope

Tags: compound-assignment, effectively-final

I have one map object named `itemClassificationMap` that gets its value from `readClassificationData()` method of `ApachePOIExcelUtil` class.

```
Map<String, ItemClassification> itemClassificationMap = new ApachePOIExcelUtil().readClassificationData("dummy");
```

The `readClassificationData()` method of `ApachePOIExcelUtil` class throws exception hence it is to be called within a try catch block.

```
try {
    Map<String, ItemClassification> itemClassificationMap = new ApachePOIExcelUtil().readClassificationData("dummy");
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But this way the map object's scope gets confined to above try catch block hence not accessible later.

If I refactor in following way

```
Map<String, ItemClassification> itemClassificationMap = null;
try {
    itemClassificationMap = new ApachePOIExcelUtil().readClassificationData("dummy");
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

compilation fails at the place down the line where it is being accessed inside a lambda expression complaining

> Local variable itemClassificationMap defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final

The error becomes

> The local variable itemClassificationMap may not have been initialized

if I refactor in following way.

```
final Map<String, ItemClassification> itemClassificationMap;
try {
    itemClassificationMap = new ApachePOIExcelUtil().readClassificationData("dummy");
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Right now I am managing with following solution which is temporary one

```
Map<String, ItemClassification> itemClassificationMapTemp = null;
try {
    itemClassificationMapTemp = new ApachePOIExcelUtil().readClassificationData("dummy");
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
Map<String, ItemClassification> itemClassificationMap = itemClassificationMapTemp;
```

and expecting an even more professional way to handle the scenario. Java experts .. comments please...

Answer (score 0):

The variable used inside Lambda needs to be final or effectively final. You can refer [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-lambda-effectively-final-local-variables). For your use case, I think you can use your second code and make a duplicate final variable to use it inside Lambda.